# Loading url image array add to UIcollectionview

Tags: objective-c, arrays, uicollectionview

I want to load images array from Url and add to `UICollectionView`

```
Tony.pageImages =imagearray;
[Tony reloadData];
NSLog(@"imagearray%@",imagearray);
```

Tony is Collection view.h/m files. `pageImages` is `NSMutableArray` on the `Tony.h` files. The Image array display console log mean i got image array correctly
Those are Url.
but when  i add code on the `UICollectionView` method it doesn't work

```
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{

UICollectionViewCell *cell = 

[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

UIImageView *CollectionViewImage = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:120];

CollectionViewImage.image= [UIImage imageNamed:self.pageImages[indexPath.row]];

 return cell;

}
```

Do i miss something ?

This is my imagearray

imagearray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

```
for (int i = 0;i < comment.count; i++)
```

{

[imagearray addObject:comment[i][@"pic_url"]] ;

}

Comment: If you have URL in your array first you need download image from that URL in background on completion you need set that image for image view

Comment: Can you edit your answer and show your imageArray? That's the key detail in your problem.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
NSData * imageData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString:self.pageImages[indexPath.row]]];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData: imageData];
CollectionViewImage.image = image;
```

This is solution how solve problem loading image from url,without addition frameworks such as "Heneke","AFNetworking"..etc..In Objective C Image View can't communicated with URL directly, but can using NSData as Helper Object(wrapper).

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please add some more information to your answer. How is your code supposed to fix the initial problem? It is likely that your post will be deleted due to poor quality, otherwise.

Comment: Actually,it's work but i curious had other way to made loading  efficiency be better because when the image is loading cause app lag for a while anyway,thanks^^

Comment: If you want to load images efficiently you can simply use "Heneke"  framework https://github.com/Haneke/Haneke ,and add: NSURL *url =[NSURL URLWithString:self.pageImages[indexPath.row]];  [CollectionViewImage  hnk_setImageFromURL:url];

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement and set the following dataSource delegate `UICollectionViewDataSource` in your viewcontroller:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
     numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return imagearray.count;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I got it right, you need to load image from URL.
To do that simply add this code:

```
[CollectionViewImage.image setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:self.pageImages[indexPath.row]] placeholderImage:nil];
```

Or if you want to add placeholder image, just set `placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"someImageInYourAssets"];`

Comment: UIimageView doesn't have "setImageWithURL" the method from AFNetworking~~~~~